# Member cannot be called after installing pynacl

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making on a `discord` bot, but I can't call up the build member after installing the `pynacl` module.

This is the code.

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, who, * ,msg):
    await ctx.guild.get_member_named(who).send()
```

And this is an error about code.

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of discord.py. I prefer you run

```
pip install discord -U
pip install discord.py -U
```

in terminal as their is a major change in docs.

Then,

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user:discord.Member, *, msg):
  await user.send(msg)
```

Comment: Thanks, but guild.members still don't work. What's wrong with this?

Comment: You were using by name it is used when you don't tag someone but use its username to dm. guild.members returns a list of members in a guild. if you have more problems in your code like this or you have any issue you can contact their developers team found in their [Api Server](https://discord.gg/discord-api)